# How to write items to a directory and call them, Objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsurl, nsfilemanager, directory

Hi I have a bunch of photos that I download from the web and I want to store them in a directory so I dont have to reload photos already downloaded, I am having trouble understanding how exactly to do this and store the photos and reload them from the directory and such. This is what I have so far. Could someone please explain the steps involved and how to do it? Thanks

```
-(void) savePhotoInCache: (NSData*) photoToSave{
   //I dont know if u need bundle ID?
   // NSString * bundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray * directoryPaths = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSLog(@"%@", directoryPaths);
NSURL* dirPath = nil;    
 //Does this create a file in my cache Directory to store my photos?
dirPath = [[directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"photos.jpg"]];
NSError* theError = nil;
[fm createDirectoryAtURL:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&theError];
// Saves the photo to the file?
[photoToSave writeToURL: dirPath atomically:NO];

NSLog(@"%@", dirPath);
//I get a deprecated warning, new version needs encoding, but I did not specify encoding in writeToURL so what do I use?
NSString * contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:dirPath ];

//After this how to I access my files and check what the contents of the file are? also, how do I limit the amount of information it stores? thanks

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this to how to get saved contents like this:

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirPath error:nil];
```

Now filter contains like this:

```
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.jpg'"];
NSPredicate *fltr1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png'"];
NSArray *onlyJPGs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
NSArray *onlyPNGs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr1];
```

To get all image content

```
for(NSString *fileName in dirContents)
{
    NSString *imgPath = [dirPath stringByAppendingFormat:fileName];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
    //You have image use it where u want
}
```

If u have many images then use lazy loading of images

Comment: I get an error when I use NSString *imgPath = [dirPath stringByAppendingFormat:[]]; It says that NSURL doesnt declare stringByAppendingFormat

Comment: I also get an error when I use NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirPath error:nil]; claiming NSURL fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to handle everything by yourself. I would rather use [EGO Image Loader](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/) which does pretty everything for you. it saves (cached) images in application bundle directory and reuse them whenever you need it. As far as study the classes, it uses the image url as primary key (to retrieve the image from cache).
Its pretty fast and Asynchronous.

Just add it to your project and call it like this:(This is ARC, so I don't use -release)

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[EGOImageView alloc] initWithPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 44.0f, 320.0f,54.0f);
imageView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com/1.jpg"] ;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

I hope it's useful.

Comment: For the task I am doing I require that I create a directory and store files in it, do U know how to do that? Also, what exactly is ARC?

Comment: thats this solution does pretty same. it uses application bundle directory to keep the files. and ARC is Automatic Reference Counting which provides automatic object and reference counting and releasing them when they no longer in use. So you don;t need to worry about releasing the objects or memory leaks